# Keypress Event on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to fire a keypress event like `ENTER` and trigger my method but I can't find any reference about doing a keypress event in xaml and call it on my view model

Could someone throw some reference. Please thanks.

Comment: You will need a CustomRenderer for an Entry . And handle the logic in specific platform

Comment: Did you googled enough? I just googled and Find a reference https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80116/how-can-i-detect-key-events-in-xamarin-forms
and there's many other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input view (Entry or Editor) has to show the Keyboard first, therefore handle the TextChanged event of the input view.

First attach the event:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtEntry.TextChanged += TxtEntry_TextChanged;
    }
```

Then handle the event

```
    void TxtEntry_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtEntry.TextChanged -= TxtEntry_TextChanged;
        char key = e.NewTextValue?.Last() ?? ' ';

        if (key == 'A')
        {
            //do something 
        }


        txtEntry.TextChanged += TxtEntry_TextChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Can just subscribe to the TextChanged event in XAML, without assigning a name to the view element.  I.e. Editor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor#textchanged

Comment: TextChanged event works fine for printable characters.  Can anyone share code on how to capture function keys, alt, control, and/or shift keys?  This is on Maui with a hardware keyboard (Zebra Scan Gun).  I'm trying to capture when the F1 key is pressed.