# How to detect keyboard inputs?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I want to detect when a key on the keyboard is pressed to execute a command. So that when I press the `F` key it does an action. How I can do it?

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181132/keypress-event-on-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to process the keyboard events like [`KeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown?view=winui-3.0). These provide you with events on every key press or release.

Inside the Event handler you need to filter which key was pressed and execute whatever action needs to be done:

```
public void MyKeyDownEventHandler(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == 70)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("'F' key pressed");
        }
}
```

Since the `KeyDown` event is bound to a control and will only be fired when the control has focus you need to think about from which control you want the event to be fired from. In order to get the event fired from everywhere in your app, [this blog post](http://madprops.org/blog/wpf-textbox-selectall-on-focus/) provides a neat solution:

By registering the `KeyDown` event to all controls during startup of your app, it will always fire as long as your app is in focus since there is always one control in focus. To achieve this, add this to the `OnStartup()` method of your app (inside the app.xaml.cs):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Control),
            Control.KeyDownEvent,
            new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyDownEventHandler));

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but MAUI don't know KeyRoutedEventArgs or I can't put it in the viewModel

Comment: Are you missing any using directives?

Comment: the System.Windows.Input?

Comment: Jep, This is the one that does the trick for me.

Comment: Is the function called constantly or do I have to do something in particular for it to be the case

Comment: The `OnStartup` method is only called on the startup of the app. Then, every time a key is pressed (while any control of your UI has focus), the KeyDownEvent is triggered which calls your `MyKeyDownEventHandler`.

Comment: I have this error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'KeyRoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: it proposes me to use one.ui

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245040/discussion-between-felix-and-waterlok).

Comment: New to MAUI here -- starting from the template, I only see the MauiProgram.cs file where there is a static class which cannot have any "OnStartup" method overloaded. Where can I register the event handler? I can only see the `builder` to which I can provide `Services`.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear whether you use xamarin or Maui, there are also some differences, about `MauiProgram.cs`. I think it overrides onstartup replace `MauiProgram.cs`. So, friends here who solve or find the answer of keydown event in Maui? THE ToolMakerSteven, I don't know who he is, but he tells that will have to wait until .net 8, maybe...

Comment: For non answer feedbacks, post a comment instead of answering.

Comment: yes，Im new for write something here ,thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34365492)

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard accelerators are in MAUI .NET 8. A `KeyboardAccelerator` can be attached to a `MenuFlyoutItem` by adding to its `KeyboardAccelerators` collection.

This can be added to `ContentPage.MenuBarItems` as follows

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="File">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="F" Clicked="MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Key="F" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
        </MenuBarItem>
    </ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MenuFlyoutItem {((MenuFlyoutItem)sender).Text} clicked");
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/keyboard-accelerators?view=net-maui-8.0