# .net maui custom entry keypress event handling

Tags: .net, events, custom-controls, keyboard-events, maui

Is there a way to capture keypress event for a custom entry control in .Net Maui? for example if i have the class:

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{

}
```

And I want to perform an action everytime a user for example presses the tab key on his keyword while he is typing/focusing the entry.

Comment: Do you need to use the tab key? Could you choose another key? I'm asking this because tab has a specific function (focus next component) and I'm not sure you can override it.

Comment: Maybe like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358210/how-to-detect-keyboard-inputs

Comment: There was no EventManager that could be used, and also it dont have to be tab, it can also be for example shift + space.

Comment: Has anyone found an answer to this?  From what I can tell Maui does not support KeyPress, KeyUp, KeyDown events.  I'm using a Zebra scan-gun and trying to capture the Function keys F1 through F12 or P1 and P2 keys.  They do not trigger anything in the TextChanged event which seems to be the only event close.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use a character which is recognized by the `Entry`, this could work for you.

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{
    public MyEntry()
    {
        TextChanged += MyEntry_TextChanged;
    }

    private void MyEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldTextValue != null
            && e.NewTextValue.Length <= e.OldTextValue.Length)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.NewTextValue.Last() == /*Insert your character here*/)
        {
            // Do your things
        }
    }
}
```

This won't work if the key you press on your keyboard has some other meaning which is not recognized as a character to write inside the `Entry`.

Comment: Thank you, but i was indeed looking for a shift + backspace or a tab which would not cause this event to fire.