# How To Detect When Any Key Pressed in .NET MAUI (KeyDown Event Handler)

Tags: .net, keypress, maui, onkeypress

I am not sure if its possible in .NET MAUI. Is anyone found solution to detect key press (including Special keys )?

Comment: Did you google the title of your question? Can see previous similar questions on SO [with this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+To+Detect+When+Any+Key+Pressed+in+.NET+MAUI+site:stackoverflow.com). **UPDATE** I just noticed you mention Special keys, so the existing answers may not apply. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360158/199364, in your Windows folder.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I need to detect when the P1 or F1 key is pressed on a Zebra Scan Gun.  The only event that comes close is the "TextChanged" event but that doesn't fire when a non-printable character key is pressed.  I'm looking into the Zebra StageNow app to remap a key to send an intent.  Maybe that's not the right way to go.  Perhaps remap the key to replace P1 with a "+" key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature that is not available out of the box in Maui, but is feasable for Windows and Android.

For android you can subclass [this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback)

For Windows you can hook into the native keyboard system using [this library.](https://github.com/TolikPylypchuk/SharpHook)

Comment: Is there any equivalent for Mac?

Comment: Nevermind, actually Sharphook is multiplatform!

Comment: Do you have any example as per how to configure Sharphook for MAUI or ASP core apps?

Comment: @alelom I was able to get it work using https://github.com/TolikPylypchuk/SharpHook/discussions/22

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard accelerators are in MAUI .NET 8. A `KeyboardAccelerator` can be attached to a `MenuFlyoutItem` by adding to its `KeyboardAccelerators` collection.

This can be added to `ContentPage.MenuBarItems` as follows

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
        <MenuBarItem Text="File">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Down" Clicked="MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Down" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Up" Clicked="MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Up" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Left" Clicked="MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Left" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Right" Clicked="MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
                    <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Right" />
                </MenuFlyoutItem.KeyboardAccelerators>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>
        </MenuBarItem>
    </ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MenuFlyoutItem {((MenuFlyoutItem)sender).Text} clicked");
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/keyboard-accelerators?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: cool solution, is there anyway to hide the menus?