# How do I register keyboard (keyDown/keyUp) in .net Maui for windows?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-windows

I'm playing around with .net Maui, and would like to capture keyboard events.
In my current application I am only targeting Windows and find myself missing the old Form system where I could just do the following.

```cs
private window = new Form();
window.KeyUp += Window_KeyUp;
window.KeyDown += Windwo_KeyDown;
```

I understand that its not as straight forward in Maui as its build with touch screens in mind, but the lack of keyboard controls is annoying.

I have tried different keyboard listening implementation, but I keep running in to documentation from Xanmarin or outdated versions of Maui.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Detect When Any Key Pressed in .NET MAUI (KeyDown Event Handler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250778/how-to-detect-when-any-key-pressed-in-net-maui-keydown-event-handler)

Comment: @TheTanic, SharpHook isnt exactly what I was hoping for but i might be able to use it. Ill see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

You can register the keyboard events(KeyUp/KeyDown) in the [PageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.handlers.pagehandler?view=net-maui-7.0) and call them respectively for MAUI Windows.

You can refer to the sample code(palced in `MauiProgram.cs`):

```
         public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp() 
      {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                  });

            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PageHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(PageHandler), (handler, view) =>
            {
#if WINDOWS
               
                handler.PlatformView.PreviewKeyUp += MAUI_Windows_PreviewKeyUp;
                        handler.PlatformView.PreviewKeyDown += MAUI_Windows_PreviewKeyDown;
#endif
            });
        ;

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
      }

#if WINDOWS
private static void MAUI_Windows_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)    
{      
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Key);   
}

private static void MAUI_Windows_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)    
{
         if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0)
             {                       
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Key);
         }
 }
#endif
```

Comment: So i register this in MauiProgram after CreatBuilder? How would i then listen for the events?

Comment: Thanks for the update, it's in the builder configuration, I've added the whole code, you can refer to it.

Comment: I see, thank you. Im a bit confused to how i then listen for the keyUp?Down event in a service/window

Comment: For example, when you use keybaord to input in a [Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry) or [Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor), the KeyEvent would be automatically listened and raised.

Comment: Sorry i have been trying to make it work. But no, my goal would be to have a system where I can register keyevents in a window without having to be in a entry/editor. I would like to add custom controlls to the window. So far @TheTanics solution using SharpHook is working the best

Comment: @Thomas That's OK. Thanks for the update.