# Namespace KeyRoutedEventArgs could not be found even when using using System.Windows.Input in net maui?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I was checking docs of net maui, but could not found how to detect key press including normal, combos and function keys. I checked at one post [How to detect keyboard inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72358210/how-to-detect-keyboard-inputs) and tried using

```
#if WINDOWS
public void MyKeyDownEventHandler(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == 27)
        {
            //code here
        }
}
#endif
```

but even after

```
#if WINDOWS
using System.Windows.Input;
#endif
```

it gives error namespace KeyRoutedEventArgs could not be found.

I expect to be able to detect at least normal and function keys in C# code. I also want to detect Combo of keys but not necessary.

Comment: 1. There should be a standard way to query or detect whether a physical keyboard exists, and there's an existing thread: github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739 and github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3858 for it. 2.Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: Can you please explain clearly? I already have given minimal reproducible example on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It would be better to provide the project via github link.

Comment: I have just started making a project to learn so I do not think that making useless(incomplete) project on github would be a good idea.

Comment: If you still say, I might provide files code if you want with links(not on github).

Comment: Can you please reply what files you need, so that I can post link to them?

Comment: Just post the files that able to reproduce the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for being late. Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ot6GEVyQqrBoi4_PjrqSQsQbp34ByyUO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tha's fine.  As I said Maui does not yet have general keyboard support cross-platform: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739. However, if change the namespace to 
`using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input`  , it just showed the data transformation error, then next step is trying to convent the `VirtualKey` to `int`. Or you can comment it out, it can compile successfully.

Comment: I was not able to convert virtual key to int. So I tried to inlcude ```using System.Windows.Input;
using Windows.System;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Core;``` and used virtualkey.escape to compare e.key but I tested with ```Application.Current.Quit();``` inside function and it did not execute.

Comment: Now, I also tried ```(int)e.Key==27``` but the function I call inside do not execute.

Comment: In app.xaml.cs, I did not include mentioned in post, might be the issue. But there are some errors I am getting like StartupEventArgs,EventManager,Control not found in that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In conclusion, there should be a standard way to detect whether a physical keyboard is **pressed** or check **key status** like below.And if so, to use its functionality.

```
var isNumLockToggled = Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.NumLock);
var isCapsLockToggled = Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.CapsLock);
var isScrollLockToggled = Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.Scroll);
```

However, this hasn't been supported. You can follow up the links below.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3858

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9764

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739

Comment: Ok, so it still needs to be implemented. Thanks for informing.